# how to select first N packets of flows in pcap file?

Tags: wireshark, pcap

I have a pcap file that has 700 udp flows.

I want to select first N (say 5) packets of each flow and discard other packets of that flow and then merge them into 1 pcap. So the pcap file would have (700*5) packets and each 5 packets belong to one flow.

Is there any program to do this?

If not, what's the easiest way to do it.

I am using is Linux

Answer (score -1):

Use the [editcap](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/editcap.html) utility which is distributed with Wireshark.

`editpcap -c 1000 input.pcap output.pcap`

Command will split `input.pcap` up into captures with a maximum of 1000 packets per capture. The output will be multiple capture files formatted like `output_{index}_{timestamp}.pcap`.

Comment: I have already used this command (but with -r switch). what i want is that i need to capture first N packets of each flow in a pcap file. what you have written, just captures first 1000 packets of a pcap file without regarding different flows.

Comment: The correct command is `editcap`, not `editpcap`.